# "Move to trash" removes files permanently

Tags: delete

I noticed that in some cases "move to trash" works as it is supposed to but in other cases it displays the warning that the files will be removed permanently. What is the reason behind such an erratic behavior and how to make sure that if I choose "Move to trash" option, the files will be actually moved to trash?

Answer (score 1):

The trash folder is limited.  Are you noticing that only large files are being deleted instead of moved?

Comment: Yes, that is actually right. I have not mentioned it in the question. Is it possible to expand the size of the Trash?

Comment: I think this depends on your distro and desktop.  I'm not really comfortable answering it.  Do some research and you will probably find something. One advantage of using Ubuntu is it's flexibility so I would be very surprised if you are not able to accomplish this.

Comment: Alright, I also noticed that the problem appears not only with the big files but also with a large number of small files (e.g. txt files).